# Closed Forms of Certain Zeta constants?

Tags: riemann-zeta, closed-form, constants

The Riemann Zeta function $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$ converges for $\operatorname{Re}(s)>1$. I am interested in some particular "irrational " values of it such as:

- $\zeta(\pi)=1.176241738\ldots$,
- $\zeta(e)=1.2690096043\ldots$,
- $\zeta(\sqrt2)=3.020737679\ldots$,
- $\ldots$

Are there closed form representations for these and constants? Are there formulas which consists of these constants?

Comment: The Riemann Zeta Function exists for all complex numbers *except* for $\;z=1\;$ ....Perhaps you meant the summatory form $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^s}\;,\;\;\text{which converges for Re}\,(s)>1\; ?$$

Comment: Yes that. Specially !and @DonAntonio does the Riemann zeta function exists for $0$ too?

Comment: Yes Shivam: for any complex  value except $\;1\;$ .

Comment: In some sense, $\zeta(\sqrt{2})$ is *already* a closed form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason to suspect that these have a "closed form". There isn't even a known closed form for $\zeta(3)$...